# Which SaltStack returners work properly with master_job_cache?

Tags: mongodb, saltstack

I've been working to set up an external returner on the master side for my Saltstack deployment -- a 'master_job_cache', [as specified in the documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jobs/external_cache.html).

I started with Slack and mongo_return.  I quickly discovered that neither of these work with master_job_cache.  My understanding is that they do not implement the right functions to make this work, particularly save_load (revelaed through searching and reading the logs).  I then tried mongo_future_return, given that it implements the correct functions -- with the understanding that according to the docs it is currently unstable.  I've got pymongo installed and my master-side configuration looks like this:

```
returner: mongo_future_return

mongo:
    db: salt_returns
    host: 194.168.1.4
    user: salt_master
    password: solidWellBuiltPassword
    port: 27017

master_job_cache: mongo_future_return
```

However, this results in a stack trace when I run it, with the master side logs telling me:

```
 Could not deserialize msgpack message.This often happens when trying to read a file not in binary modeTo see message payload, enable debug logging and retry. Exception: unpack(b) received extra data.
```

So, first question: given what I've explained so far, is there anything I appear to be doing incorrectly that I should address in order to make these mongo returners work?

Second, and main question: what returners have worked for you with the master_job_cache option?  Is there a list of those THAT WORK WITH MASTER JOB CACHE (I know there is a list of returners, many don't specify). I don't have the time to try each one individually, though I will likely give MySQL and Postgres a shot.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the MySQL master job cache successfully many times.

Comment: The question wasn't "have you used it". It was "which returns have you used it with".

Comment: HI @Utah_Dave, thanks for the response.  I've actually decided to go with the Postgresql master job cache, and it's working beautifully.  Thanks for your work on Saltstack, I love the product, it's become a core pillar of our automation strategy.  I'm going to leave this question up for a little bit and see if it accumulates any additional relevant info.  Cheers!

Comment: @JennyD, I've used the MySQL master job cache, which is the MySQL returner. I'm not sure how I'm not answering his question.